# Concatenate getters results with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

As a user requirement i have to extract data from a few different Excel files and for each of them concatenate their values (for each row, converted to strings where needed) to save the result to DB.
I already have mapped those excel files to a different bean (POJO) for each of them.
What i would like to do is to call every getter by reflection and , with a single method, handle all of them (and their future modifications!) without having to manually invoke each getter (easy, but error-prone and requesting a code change for every excel file modification).
This is what i've got so far :

```
public String getConcatenatedValues(Class beanClass, Object myBean) throws IntrospectionException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{

    String output = "";

    for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass, BeanBase.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){

        Method myMethod = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
        Object resultFromGetter = myMethod.invoke(myBean);
//missing logic here

        output += resultFromGetter.toString();
    }


    return output;
}
```

BaseBean here is a class every bean extends of which i do not want to call the getters. I'm only interested in beanClass getters.
What i'd need is a dynamic cast to the class returned by myMethod.getReturnType()
to be able to call the toString() method of the correct class.
Is this a correct approach? Is it doable by reflection alone?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) as it seems to fit the requierment. specifically, [PropertyUtils.describe()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe(java.lang.Object)) gives you complete list of getters for a given POJO, while `PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(pojo, propName)` will give you the value of a specified property (as an Object), handling the reflection calls internally. of course there is also `PropertyUtils.getPropertyType(pojo, propName)` if you need

Comment: Or `ToStringBuilder` is great too.